# How to Analyze Data to optimize committee Allocations?

Tags: optimization, dataset, excel

On Google Sheets, I have collected responses from my team members to assign them to be committee members in any of the 4 following committees: Internal, External, Membership, Speaker Management. Everyone should be in at least one committee but can be in more than 1. Additionally, they had the option to indicate whether they would like to be the chair of any of these committees, where they can only chair one committee or indicate NONE in the poll if they would not like to. Every committee needs at least one chair and at most 3. Here is how the data looks like:

| Name | Committee Membership Interest | Committee Chair Interest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Johnson | External Relations | Internal Relations |
| Apple Appleson | Internal Relations, External Relations | None |
| Banana Bonso | Internal Relations, Membership, External Relations | None |
| Carter Cartwheel | Internal Relations, Speaker Management | Internal Relations, Speaker Management |
| Denzel Donson | Membership, External Relations | Membership, External Relations |
| Fred Fritz | Speaker Management | Speaker Management |
| Sick Somber | Internal Relations, Speaker Management, External Relations | None |
| Zeta Zeronson | Membership | None |

Using this information, how might I analyze the data to optimize allocation of these members to the various committees? I would ideally like to know how many people are interested in each committee, how many want to be the chair of which committee, etc. Any tips or tricks on what I can do to make this process easy on google sheets?

Comment: Depending on the number of team members and their preferences, criteria may conflict. You will need to clarify which criterion is most important:  preferences about chairing, preferences for committees, or rule that everyone serve on a committee. // Requests to use specific software are usually 'off topic'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of assignment problem is computational really really difficult. There's actually a fun mini-documentary on Youtube about how the NFL does their schedule ever year. In essence they create a set of constraints (similar to your employees preferences) and then have a big computer run and score millions of possible solutions and then they manually review the top few. You can look at the "assignment problem" Wikipedia page for a few little proofs, but essentially what it comes down to is that there isn't any special solution or mathematical trick. You have to kind of just choose a way to score the quality of the assignments and try to find a clever algorithm to create a good schedule. This is probably the best option if your comfortable with a little R/Python. A very simple algorithm might be:

1. Of those interested in being a committee chairs, randomly select committee chairs. If there is a committee no one wants to be assigned to, pick a sucker at random. Perhaps someone who gave you very few options if you want to punish them for being difficult.
2. Start with the least popular committee; randomly select from those interested in that committee and assign them to it. If you run out of people interested in that committee, move on.
3. Repeat step 2 for each committee, but only assign each individual to 1 committee maximum.
4. Once steps 2 & 3 are complete, take any individuals who do not yet have a committee assignment (hopefully very few or none) and assign them to a random empty committee spot.
5. For any remaining empty spots, repeat steps 2-4, but instead constrain individuals to a maximum of 2 committee assignments.
6. Once finished score the completed schedule. Something like 1 points for each committee someone is on that they don't want to be on, 2 points for a committee assignment that someone is on they don't want to be on AND is there second assignment.

A computer can do this pretty quick. So you could generate 10's 100's or 1000's (or more) of potential schedules and pick from among those with low scores.

If you were hoping for something in excel... well...